# Nest non-blade layout in Laravel?

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a master layout with `@yield('content')` but I need my controller to inject a non-blade file into the content section. How can I achieve this?

I've tried in my controller:

```
protected $layout = 'master';

public function showWelcome()
{
  $this->layout->nest('content', 'welcome')->render();
}
```

Where welcome is an not a blade file. Is this possible or just a limitation of Laravel?

Comment: Where is this 'welcome' comming from? Is it a html file? Or something else? Is the file on the server or on a remote host?

Comment: It's just a file on the side directory. Could be html or php.

Comment: Non-blade layout can only be inserted through @include.